# Difference between Java EE 5 and Java EE 6

Tags: jakarta-ee

What are the main differences of Java EE 5 and Java EE 6 ?

Comment: "J2EE" was used for version 1.2 until with 1.4. After 1.5 (5.0, 5, five, whatever) over 5 years ago it became "Java EE". I fixed your question. Keep yourself updated :)

Answer (score 11):

Oracle has a three part article detailing the changes: [Introducing the Java EE 6 Platform: Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/javaee6overview-141808.html)

Answer (score 6):

I know it's kind of nitpicky but the enterprise editions dropped the "2" from their acronyms sometime ago, it's Java EE 5 / Java EE 6 now. For differences between the two, its easy enough to simply look at the specs:

Java EE 6 http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316

Java EE 5 http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=244

Honestly some of the major things that they have added have been available in Spring for quite some time dependency injection and bean validation.